# A key strength of this design

Tags: word-meaning

Does "strength" here mean "power or ability (to do things that need a lot of physical or mental effort)"?

> Vaccine effectiveness was estimated with a test-negative case–control study design, a preferred design for assessing vaccine effectiveness against influenza (see the Supplementary Appendix).2 **A key strength of this design** is the ability to control for bias that may result from differences in health care–seeking behavior between vaccinated and unvaccinated persons.

Source: [New England Journal of Medicine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMc2104974)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Strength" refers to the strong attribute of the design, which is Sense 4a in Merriam-Webster Dictionary:

> **4b: a strong attribute or inherent asset** 
> // the *strengths* and the weaknesses of the book are evident
>
> ([Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strength), n. d.)